PreLoad livestream videos in mobile app (Android)
I am creating a mobile app on android. I have implemented Live streaming module in it using WebRTC. The user can scroll through multiple live streams at a time. The problem that I am facing is that there is a 2-3 seconds loading time for each live stream before it is played. I want the live stream to play instantly like it does in tiktok. I am also open for a solution using any other live streaming protocol.
I am using a recyclerview to play the list of livestreams that one at a time.
  webRTCClient!!.config.remoteVideoRenderers.add(viewHolder.mBinding.cameraViewRenderer); //adding SurfaceViewRenderer when playing video

  webRTCClient!!.play(streamId)

  webRTCClient!!.config.remoteVideoRenderers.clear()// clearing SurfaceViewRenderer before playing next video

The problem is when the stream is played for the first time the loading time is 2-3 seconds. I want to play the stream as soon as the user scroll to it

Please [edit] your question and add a [mre] that displays the undesired behavior and describe in more detail what you would want to be different.
